# atlassian crowd and omniauth_crowd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, atlassian-crowd

I am using ruby-1.9, rails 3, and I am trying to login into crowd server using omniauth_crowd library. The configuration is very easy:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :crowd, :crowd_server_url=>"http://some-crowd-server/crowd", :application_name=>"app-dev", :application_password=>"app-pass"
end
```

Also /auth/callback and /auth/failed is routed, but when I am trying to authenticate,
just after the login form when callback is called - I got:

```
uninitialized constant OmniAuth::Strategies::Crowd::CrowdValidator::Net
```

From looking into 'omniauth/strategies/crowd/crowd_validator.rb' I could
see a call  Net:HTTP ... so I think I have not included some gem or else,
but not so experienced in ruby and have no idea now about what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds silly, but I ran into the same problem until I remembered to add my app server's IP to the application's list of allowed remote IPs. Try that.